# Can someone explain and uses of isLocal property in JQuery Ajax in timezone issues?

Tags: jquery, timezone

Can someone explain and uses of isLocal property in JQuery Ajax and how its related to system's timezone?

Answer (score 0):

**isLocal**

Default: dependant upon current location protocol

Allow the current environment (the filesystem) to be recognized as "local," even if jQuery doesn't recognize it as such by default.

- The following protocols are currently recognized as local: file,
  *-extension, and widget.
- If the isLocal setting needs modifying, do this once in the
  jQuery.ajaxSetup() method.